# Installing server with cloud-init script?

Tags: server, system-installation, cloud-init, subiquity

I just installed a (physical, bare metal) server with the new 21.10 server install image (in order to test and prepare for 22.04) on a usb pendrive.

Worked, but I did not see an option to tell the installer to use a cloud-init file from my webserver, which would not just ease installation, but ensure, that several servers are installed exactly the same way.

How can I have the 21.10/22.04 server installation use a given cloud-init file from a webserver instead of that interactive dialog (except from pxe/maas installation)?

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you run thru the Subiquity Terminal UI, there is no cloud-init option.  However, if you have a look at autoinstall, as part of that you can supply a `user-data` section and include the cloud-init things there.

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the grub kernel line on the installer media. You would need to include options such as 'autoinstall' and also 'datasource(ds)' to the kernel line. E.g

```
autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://10.10.0.1:8000/
```

In addition to the autoinstall references mentioned above, you should refer to cloud-init documentation especially on Nocloud source.

https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html